# capture pattern_X repeatedly, then capture pattern_Y once, then repeat until EOS

Tags: python, regex, parsing, non-greedy, sql-parser

*[update:] Accepted answer suggests, this can not be done with the python `re` library in one step. If you know otherwise, please comment.*

I'm reverse-engineering a massive ETL pipeline, I'd like to extract the full data lineage from stored procedures and views.

I'm struggling with the following regexp.

```py
import re

select_clause = "`data_staging`.`CONVERT_BOGGLE_DATE`(`landing_boggle_replica`.`CUST`.`u_birth_date`) AS `birth_date`,`data_staging`.`CONVERT_BOGGLE_DATE`(`landing_boggle_replica`.`CUST`.`u_death_date`) AS `death_date`,(case when (isnull(`data_staging`.`CONVERT_BOGGLE_DATE`(`landing_boggle_replica`.`CUST`.`u_death_date`)) and (`landing_boggle_replica`.`CUST`.`u_cust_type` <> 'E')) then timestampdiff(YEAR,`data_staging`.`CONVERT_BOGGLE_DATE`(`landing_boggle_replica`.`CUST`.`u_birth_date`),curdate()) else NULL end) AS `age_in_years`,nullif(`landing_boggle_replica`.`CUST`.`u_occupationCode`,'') AS `occupation_code`,nullif(`landing_boggle_replica`.`CUST`.`u_industryCode`,'') AS `industry_code`,((`landing_boggle_replica`.`CUST`.`u_intebank` = 'Y') or (`sso`.`u_mySecondaryCust` is not null)) AS `online_web_enabled`,(`landing_boggle_replica`.`CUST`.`u_telebank` = 'Y') AS `online_phone_enabled`,(`landing_boggle_replica`.`CUST`.`u_hasProBank` = 1) AS `has_pro_bank`"

# this captures every occurrence of the source fields, but not the target
okay_pattern = r"(?i)((`[a-z0-9_]+`\.`[a-z0-9_]+`)[ ,\)=<>]).*?"

# this captures the target too, but captures only the first input field
wrong_pattern = r"(?i)((((`[a-z0-9_]+`\.`[a-z0-9_]+`)[ ,\)=<>]).*?AS (`[a-z0-9_]+)`).*?)"

re.findall(okay_pattern, select_clause)
re.findall(wrong_pattern, select_clause)
```

TLDR: I'd like to capture

```
[aaa, bbb, XXX],
[eee, fff, ..., ooo, YYY],
[ppp, ZZZ]
```

from a string like

```
"...aaa....bbb...XXX....eee...fff...[many]...ooo... YYY...ppp...ZZZ...."
```

where `a,b,e,f,h` match one pattern, `X,Y,Z` match another, and the first pattern might occur up to ~20 times, before the second one appears, which always appears alone.

I'm open to solutions with the `sqlglot`, `sql-metadata`, or `sqlparse` libraries as well, it is just regex is better documented.

(Probably I'm code golfing, and I should do this in several steps, starting with splitting the string into individual expressions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with 3 capture and 1 non-capture groups:

```bash
(\w+)\.+(\w+)(?:\.+(\w+))?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hKnfzX/1)

**Code:**

```py
import re
s = '...aaa....bbb...XXX....eee...fff...YYY...hhh...ZZZ....'
print (re.findall(r'(\w+)\.+(\w+)(?:\.+(\w+))?', s))
```

**Output:**

```bash
[('aaa', 'bbb', 'XXX'), ('eee', 'fff', 'YYY'), ('hhh', 'ZZZ', '')]
```

Comment: Nice and simple. How can I modify this regex to match any number of pattern_1 groups? In my example there might be up to ~20 occasions before a pattern_2 appears.

Comment: ok then how is pattern_1 defined? Does it always start with lowercase letters where `pattern_2` starts with upper case?

Comment: Also please keep in mind that we cannot grab repeated captured group in python `re`. e.g. you can use this regex: `([a-z]\w*(?:\.+[a-z]\w*){0,19})(?:\.+(\w+))?` but there will be only 2 captured groups per match.

Comment: In this case your initial proposal is as close, as I can get. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's two regexes, one to group things by the outside pattern, and one for the inside:

```
(.*?)(XXX|YYY|ZZZ)
(aaa|bbb|ccc|ddd|eee|fff|ggg)
```

What I would suggest is matching the whole string with the first regex, and then using the second regex on the first regex's match `(.*?)`

By using these two regexes, your matches will be grouped first by the outer pattern and then by the inner pattern, but the regexes themselves doesn't have to be overly complicated.